# Request body (Content-Length) is larger than the configured limit?

Tags: apache, mod-security

I have a file uploading site and am getting this error when trying to upload files larger than 400MB. Does anyone know where I can set this value? I also have ModSecurity Disabled for this account so I don't know why MS is catching this in the first place!

Thank you

Answer (score 20):

I heard setting a default for apache in httpd.conf for the *LimitRequestBody* config variable might work.

or maybe not applicable to you but if mod_security is enabled:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf
```

Has this:
SecRequestBodyLimit 131072
Change to (6MB), or what ever size you want to allow:
SecRequestBodyLimit 6000000"*

Comment: I increased the limits above and now get a new error: Server Error(403 Forbidden)

Answer (score 5):

I face this problem too in `Centos 7 / DirectAdmin` so. First you should change two variable

- SecRequestBodyLimit
- SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit

you can try this path

`/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf`

so you can edit this file in **CentOS/DirectAdmin**

`nano /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-modsecurity.conf`

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and search for

`SecRequestBodyLimit`

then change

```
SecRequestBodyLimit 131072
SecRequestBodyLimit 131072
```

to

```
SecRequestBodyLimit 8388608
SecRequestBodyLimit 8388608
```

Note: **131072 = 127KB , 8388608 = 8MB**

Hoe this work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue on CentOS 7 when using Nginx (1.14.1) as a reverse proxy for Apache.

I had already configured Nginx to allow larger request body sizes:

```
server {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    ...
}
```

But I was still getting a `413`.  To fix it, I had to add the following to the corresponding vhost config in Apache too:

```
<VirtualHost *:4321>
    <Location "/">  # Apply site-wide
        SSLRenegBufferSize 20972000
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

### Relevant documentation:

- [`client_max_body_size`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size)
- [`SSLRenegBufferSize`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrenegbuffersize)
- [413 Status Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/413)